error: initializer for flexible array member 'const char* ArgumentGuard::_args []'
I have this class I just wrote, see below. I am trying to create a utility class for checking command line arguments in the argc and argv parameters of main().
class ArgumentGuard {
public:
    ArgumentGuard() = default;
    ArgumentGuard(int& argc, char const *argv[]) : _arc{argc}, _args{*argv} {}

    bool has_arguments() const {
        return _arc < 2 ? false : true;
    }

private:
    int _arc;
    const char* _args[];
};

Usage:
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    ArgumentGuard guard(argc, argv);

Error:
In constructor 'ArgumentGuard::ArgumentGuard(int&, const char**)':
 error: initializer for flexible array member 'const char* ArgumentGuard::_args []'
   60 |     ArgumentGuard(int& argc, char const *argv[]) : _arc{argc}, _args{*argv} {}
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from sectra.cpp:1:
 In constructor 'ArgumentGuard::ArgumentGuard(int&, const char**)':
 error: initializer for flexible array member 'const char* ArgumentGuard::_args []'
   60 |     SectraArgumentGuard(int& argc, char const *argv[]) : _arc{argc}, _args{*argv} {}
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In constructor 'ArgumentGuard::ArgumentGuard(int&, const char**)':
error: initializer for flexible array member 'const char* ArgumentGuard::_args []'
   60 |     ArgumentGuard(int& argc, char const *argv[]) : _arc{argc}, _args{*argv} {}
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Aside: return _arc < 2 ? false : true; is a convoluted way of writing return _arc >= 2;.

const char* _args[] is not valid c++. See CASE 4 in the answer at [Is int arr ] valid C++?

Flexible array members are not C++ feature, it's an extension of your compiler. You should mention the compiler and its version if you want any answers here. For the time being, duplicate is correct, having only [tag:c++] tag we can deduce you want to write code according to C++ standard, if you edit the question, I can lift the closure.

While the duplicate does explain the error, I don't think it reflects what this asker was actually trying to do.  Change const char* _args[]; to const char** _args; and change _args{*argv} to _args{argv}

@DrewDormann They may want Flexible Array Member, how do you know it's not supposed to be that?

Related: Are flexible array members valid in C++?

@Yksisarvinen I based that assumption on "I am trying to create a utility class for checking command line arguments in the argc and argv parameters of main().".  That doesn't sound like flexible array work.

The syntax for C-style arrays can be tricky.
A function parameter like your char const *argv[] isn't actually an array - it's shorthand for a pointer.  It's the same as char const **argv.
Change your class so it is also managing a pointer - not an array.
class ArgumentGuard {
public:
    ArgumentGuard() = default;
    ArgumentGuard(int argc, char const *argv[]) : _arc{argc}, _args(argv) {}

    bool has_arguments() const {
        return _arc < 2 ? false : true;
    }

private:
    int _arc;
    const char** _args;
};


Also, there is no reason to pass in argc by reference just to make a copy of its value. Pass it in by value instead of by reference.

Drew, thanks. I decided to use a std::vector ;-)

Aside from VLA being a none-std extension, encapsulating a reference(int&) inside a class creates lifetime issues, resulting in dangling. All in all both members of your ArgumentGuard are troublesome.
I invite you to exploit the low-hanging fruits of modern C++, instead of trying difficult stuff and raw pointers. Command line arguments is another application for C++20 <ranges>:
#include <ranges>
int main(int argc, char const ** argv){
    using namespace std::views; //counted, transform, as_const
    auto args = counted(argv, std::size_t{argc})
              | transform([](auto s){ return std::string_view{s}; })
              | as_const;

   auto args_guard = [args]
   { return std::ranges::size(args) >= 2; };
   if (not args_guard())
       return ~0;
   //Blah blah
   return 0;
};

In the above snippet args is a fat pointer to command line arguments, which can be pass by value - as long as not to a detached thread. It has low automatic memory footprint and triggers no dynamic allocation. Each command line argument is viewed as a std::string_view. Thus the only case of explicit pointer use is now the inevitable initialization from argv.
This snippet achieves a great deal of safety at absolute zero-cost.

This is a great and modern solution, although I don't agree that initializing a std::string_view from every const char* has "absolute zero-cost".  This is the only code that iterates over every character.

@DrewDormann conversion to string_view is the only option that prevents using raw string pointers. The length calculation cost is compensated when string_view object is used within an expression. Normally, it will be concatenated inside a formating function.

Moreover, the transformation happens only when elements are accessed. So I bet on its performance against any other conpetitor.
